# variable scope not set in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function canDeleteFacilitator(facilitatorId, handleData) {
var call = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urls.candeletefacilitator,
    data:{facilitatorId: facilitatorId}
}).done(function (data) {
    return handleData(data);
})
}   

var canDeleteText = "";
canDeleteFacilitator(facilitator.value, function (canDelete) {
    console.log(canDelete);
    if (canDelete == true) {
        canDeleteText = '<button class="badge btn-danger p-2" id="deleteFacilitator" type="button"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Delete Permanently</button>';
    }

})

console.log(canDeleteText);
```

canDeleteText does not get set within the callback function.  How do I correct this scope?

Comment: The scope is correct. You're just logging it prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

You're not **returning** anything in your function .. You should also set the `var` *within* the scope of the function unless you're going to pass it in ...  Like so ..

```
canDeleteFacilitator(facilitator.value, function (canDelete) {
    var canDeleteText = "";
    console.log(canDelete);
    if (canDelete == true) {
        canDeleteText = '<button class="badge btn-danger p-2" id="deleteFacilitator" type="button"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Delete Permanently</button>';
    }
    return canDeleteText;
})
```

In essence, `canDeleteText` should stay within the function .. And if you want to set it outside the function, you'll need to set as a **return** *of* the function:

```
var canDeleteText = canDeleteFacilitator( callbacks );
```

So a practical usage would be to set it as a function, off the get-go:

```
function canDeleteFacilitator(canDelete) {
    var canDeleteText = "";
    console.log(canDelete);
    if (canDelete == true) {
        canDeleteText = '<button class="badge btn-danger p-2" id="deleteFacilitator" type="button"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Delete Permanently</button>';
    }
    return canDeleteText;
}

var canDeleteText = canDeleteFacilitator(1); // I set it to "true" just to pass the if

console.log(canDeleteText);
```